# How do I upgrade Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, updates

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and when I boot, it asks me if I want to upgrade to the next distro. I say yes, but during that process, I get a message saying "missing file: 1.0.1 ubuntu 2.13" After that attempt, I tried updating my current system, and I get a message saying it can't update it. How can I upgrade? Thank you much!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please try again and post the precise error messages? The first one seems to miss some parts, the second one "saying it can't update it" would be nice to see as well.

Comment: Hi @Andrea Lazzarotto. Thanks for your answer. I decided to just focus on updating my existing system. The error message I got was:  "Failed to download package files. Check your Internet connection." So, I ran only the 1st two lines: exec sudo -1 and apt-get update. It listed about a page and a half of, what I think were, files it downloaded. I saved a couple of screenshots of the results, but don't know how to attach them to this comment. It seemed to run OK, but when I tried to update again, I got the same error. What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: You should add the relevant information (and screenshot) inside your question. Please edit it to include such information. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Reboot your system to finish installing updates, and to upgrade to new available version:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
update-manager -d
```

Software Updater will show up and search for the new release, after a few seconds, you will see a screen like below that saying:

However, Ubuntu 16.04 is available now.

Press the button Upgrade to start upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.

The Software Updater will ask you to confirm still you want to upgrade, press Start Upgrade to begin installing Ubuntu 16.04.

Now, the Software Updater will prepare to start setting up new software channels, and after a few minutes, the software updater will notify you the details the number of packages are going to be removed, and number of packages are going to be installed, press Start upgrade to continue.

Ended the dist-upgrade, reboot your system and:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
```